# "Ambiguous Constructor Reference" XmlSerializer

Tags: .net, generics, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize a `List<MyObject>`.  When I create my XmlSerializer as such:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(List<MyObject>);
```

I get the following error: ***Ambiguous Constructor Reference***

How can I fix this so I can serialize and deserialize my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyObject>));
```

or

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(myList.GetType());
```

You are trying use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s92ee1.aspx), but you're not passing in a Type object.